# SQL Logic to pick following business day if calendar date is Weekend or Holiday

Tags: sql, calendar, teradata

I have a Table that contains our Company Holidays (Holiday_Ind and Weekend_Ind).
Table Name - system_calendar.calendar

I'm looking to create a sql script which should pick the following business day if the Date is Weekend or Holiday:

Example - Jan 2015:

```
Date        CalendarDay#    BusinessDay#
1/1/2015    1               1
1/2/2015    2               1
1/3/2015    3               2
1/4/2015    4               2
1/5/2015    5               2
1/6/2015    6               3
1/7/2015    7               4
```

Example - Aug 2015:

```
Date        CalendarDay#    BusinessDay#
8/1/2015    1               1
8/2/2015    2               1
8/3/2015    3               1
8/4/2015    4               2
8/5/2015    5               3
8/6/2015    6               4
8/7/2015    7               5
8/8/2015    8               6
8/9/2015    9               6
8/10/2015   10              6
```

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Teradata?  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: This is a cumulative sum over a `CASE WHEN date is holiday or weekend THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Comment: What will the input and desired output look like?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this result utilizes a cumulative sum over a CASE:

```
greatest(sum(case when h_ind = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end)
         over(partition by eom
              order by dt
              rows unbounded preceding), 1)
```

The `GREATEST` for the case when the 1st day of a month is not a business day.

Hijacked @vkp's [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8e9f6/2)

Answer (score 0):

This code below would give you a close example of how to do the business day calculation. You might have to modify some of the functions to suit `teradata`.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e9f6/1)

```
select dt, h_ind,
case when h_ind = 'Y' 
then row_number() over(order by dt)-
rank() over(partition by h_ind order by dt) + 1
else rank() over(partition by h_ind order by dt) end
 as businessday
from t 
order by dt
```

Comment: vkp, this does indeed work as is in Teradata.  Only change I would make is to reset it at each EOM change.  Did that by using the following:   case when h_ind = 'Y' then row_number() over(partition by eom order by dt asc)-rank() over(partition by eom, h_ind order by dt asc) + 1
   else rank() over(partition by eom, h_ind order by dt asc) end